# Qt6 Ошибка сборки из исходников

Tags: qt6

Fedora 37

Пытаюсь собрать Qt6 - 6.4.0 из исходников.

При запуске ./configure выдает следующее:

```
Can't locate English.pm in @INC (you may need to install the English module) (@INC 
contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/5.36 /usr/local/share/perl5/5.36 
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 
/usr/share/perl5) at 
/home/****/Development/Qt/Static/6.4.0/Src/qtbase/libexec/syncqt.pl line 19.
```

Что это?
И как с этим бороться?

Comment: перлу что-то нехватает, надо доустановить

Answer (score 0):

Проблема исчезла после установки cpan